# using "this" to refer the "Context"

Tags: android, android-activity

I can get the context with methods like `getApplicationContext()` or `getContext()` but I am a little confused with using "this" to get the "context" in the following example:

```
public class GeoActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_geo);

        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // another method to get the context
                // Context context = getApplicationContext();
                Toast.makeText(GeoActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

in this code we use `GeoActivity.this` to refer to the `context`, but I didn't understand what `GeoActivity.this` really is and what it is pointing to. also why in this case we cannot use simply `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Activity is a Context. If you use "this", it refers to the object in which the "this" appears, so if you use it inside a method of an Activity, it refers to the Activity. Because an Activity is a Context, you can use "this" when you need to pass a Context.

The situation is slightly complicated by the fact that you're using "this" inside the OnClickListener. You're creating an anonymous inner class to use as your OnClickListener. That's fine, but it means that if you just use "this" inside the OnClickListener, inside the Activity, then it'll refer to the OnClickListener rather than to the Activity. If you've got nested classes like this, you can specify which instance you want to refer to by putting the class name in front of the "this". So in your Toast.makeText method, "this" would refer to the OnClickListener that's inside your Activity, but "GeoActivity.this" refers to your Activity.

Answer (score 1):

From [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) - `Activity` extends Context, so you can use `Activity` when `Context` is required

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
```